# Core latency testing ARMv8.1

Tags: c++, arm

There is an [interesting article](https://www.anandtech.com/show/15578/cloud-clash-amazon-graviton2-arm-against-intel-and-amd/2) about ARM8.1 Graviton 2 offering of AWS.
This article has tests for CPU coherency where I am trying to repeat.

There is C++ code repo in GitHub named [core-latency](https://github.com/ajakubek/core-latency) using [Nonius Micro-benchmarking](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius).

I managed to replicate the first test without atomic instructions using the command below to compile:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -o core-latency main.cpp -march=armv8-a
```

The article claims that ARMv8.1 uses [atomic CAS operations](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0801/g/A64-Data-Transfer-Instructions/CASA--CASAL--CAS--CASL--CASAL--CAS--CASL) and has much better performance.  It also provides test results that are much better.

I tried to repeat it compiling with ARMv8.1, ARMv8.2, and ARMv8.3. Sample commands for compilation are below:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -o core-latency main.cpp -march=armv8.1-a+lse
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -o core-latency main.cpp -march=armv8.2-a+lse
$ g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -o core-latency main.cpp -march=armv8.3-a+lse
```

None of these improved the performance. Because of that I got the assembly code for it using these commands:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -S main.cpp -march=armv8.1-a+lse
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -S main.cpp -march=armv8.2-a+lse
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pthread -O3 -Iinclude -S main.cpp -march=armv8.3-a+lse
```

I searched the code and cannot find any CAS operations used.
I also tried the different variations of compilation with or without "lse" and "-moutline-atomics".

I am not a C++ expert and I have a very basic understanding of it.

My guess is that [the code](https://github.com/ajakubek/core-latency) needs some changes to use atomic instructions.

Tests are executed on m6g.16xlarge EC2 instance in AWS. OS Ubuntu 20.04.

So if someone can check the core-latency code and give some insights to make sure that it compiles with CAS instructions, that will be a great help.

Comment: The "core-latency" benchmark does not appear to use *any* read-modify-write operations. It just *tries* (with a questionable approach) to measure the time it takes for a roundtrip of "write -> read" between two threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some more experiments, I found the problem.
In the code snippet below are the steps:

- making a comparison first (if state equals Ping)
- calling the class method `set` to do an atomic store operation.

Code snippet from [core-latency](https://github.com/ajakubek/core-latency/blob/master/main.cpp):

```
if (state == Ping)
   sync.set(Pong);
...
void set(State new_state)
{
  state.store(new_state);
}
```

All of the code never compiles to a CAS instruction. If you want to have an atomic compare and swap operation, you need to use the relevant method from atomic.

I have written below a sample code for experimenting:

```
#include <atomic>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
  int expected = 0;
  int desired = 1;
  std::atomic<int> current; 
  current.store(expected);
  printf("Before %d\n", current.load());
  while(!current.compare_exchange_weak(expected,desired));
  printf("After %d\n", current.load());
}
```

I compiled it for ARMv8.1 and can see that it is using CAS instruction.
I compiled it for ARMv8.0 and can see that it is not using CAS instruction (which is OK as it is not supported in this version).

So if I want to get CAS instruction sets used, I need to use `atomic::compare_exchange_weak` or `atomic::compare_exchange_strong`; otherwise, the compiler will not use CAS but compile your comparison and store operations separately.

In summary, I can rewrite the benchmark with `atomic::compare_exchange_weak` and see what results I am getting.

### New update April 30

I have created the new version of the code with atomic compare and swap support.
It is available here https://github.com/fuatu/core-latency-atomic

**Here are the test results for instance m6g.16xlarge (ARM):**

Without CAS: Average latency 245ns
[image: Without CAS]

With CAS: Average latency 39ns
[image: With CAS]